# Xcode 6 debugger shows "0 objects" for instance (even when description implemented)

Tags: debugging, xcode6

I am encountering what I think is a bug with the Xcode debugger. I am using Xcode 6.1.1.

When I try to introspect one of my custom classes, instead of seeing that it's derived from **NSObject** and its properties and values, all I see is "0 objects". It is not even an array. All my other classes allow me introspection as expected.

Yes, I have implemented the **(NSString *)description** method but that shouldn't matter as I am able to introspect another class' instance that has no **description** implemented.

Here are some screenshots from Xcode showing the class that doesn't introspect and one that does:

### Screenshots

**Screenshot 1:**
[image: WFQCountry introspection shows 0 objects]
**Screenshot 2:**
[image: WFQUserCountry introspection shows values]

### Code

**WFQCountry.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WFQCountry : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *iso3166Alpha2Code;
...
```

**WFQUserCountry.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WFQUserCountry : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *iso3166Alpha2Code;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems a simple Xcode restart fixed the problem. I wonder if Xcode got confused when I had refactored 'Country' into 'WFQCountry' and required a restart to get things back in line.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Cheers.